# How to remove key binding for Jump To Next/Previous Counterpart in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In most key bindings a small minus sign appears on the right to remove the binding, but with *Jump to Next/Previous Counterpart* it seems it is not possible to clear that one.

I want to use that key binding for a different command and I can't do it without removing it first.

When trying to delete those a small error message appears that says:

> Can't delete the keyboard shortcut because it has alternate menu items

[image]

Any idea on how to get rid of those shortcuts?

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any minus sign at all for those (probably because, as you say, they have alternates). I think your best bet here is to edit a copy of the key bindings file to make an alternate key bindings set and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @matt but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to remove them, but I "fixed" a similar situation by just changing the existing shortcut to something else I don't use. Might be tricky though if you want to remove a lot of things...
Note: it looks like "alternates" are what you can get for some menu items when you hold the option key. Your jump to next counterpart etc have alternates that open it in a separate assistant editor.